# Update apigateway deployment with cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do I update a apigateway deployment using the cli? I can find the `update-deployment` command, but I do not know what to put in for the values it needs in this skeleton (taken from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-deployment.html)):

```
{
  "op": "add"|"remove"|"replace"|"move"|"copy"|"test",
  "path": "string",
  "value": "string",
  "from": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`update-deployment` is used to update the metadata of an existing deployment. For example, to update the description of a deployment:

```
aws apigateway update-deployment \
               --rest-api-id <value> \
               --deployment-id <value> \ 
               --patch-operations 'op=replace,path=/description,value=<value>'
```

If you wanted to re-deploy an API (this is what happens when you click on "Deploy API" in the web console), you'd use the [`create-deployment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-deployment.html) command:

```
aws apigateway create-deployment \
               --rest-api-id <value> \
               --stage-name <value>
```

Comment: Mmh, I might not have been 100% clear in my question. I want to do with the cli what happens when I click "Actions _> Deploy API" under the AWS Console in apigateway.